# Rewrite this Scalar UDF as a Inline TVF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I am trying to write this scalar UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DAYSADDNOWK](@addDate AS DATE, @numDays AS INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @numDays>0
    BEGIN
       SET @addDate=DATEADD(d,1,@addDate)
       IF DATENAME(DW,@addDate)='saturday' SET @addDate=DATEADD(d,1,@addDate)
       IF DATENAME(DW,@addDate)='sunday' SET @addDate=DATEADD(d,1,@addDate)
  
       SET @numDays=@numDays-1
    END
  
    RETURN CAST(@addDate AS DATETIME)
END
GO
```

as an inline TVF.

I have been trying to use CTEs in the TVF to replace the `while` loop, but I keep running into myriad issues, so if anyone has any ideas and could help I would be incredibly grateful.

Requirements: Take in a date, `d`, and an integer, `i`, as parameters and return a date that is that is `i` many business days (weekdays) from the date, `d`, argument passed in.

While I appreciate that there may be better ways to go about this, and would love to read them if they're suggested here, I also really would like to know how to accomplish this using recursive CTE(s) in a Inline TVF as I am more doing this as practice so I can apply this technique to more complicated scalar UDF's I may need to refactor in the future.

Comment: Just feels like a Calendar Table would be more useful.   This and many other functions.

Comment: In addition to showing us code and asking us to translate it, you need to show us your requirements so we understand what you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: I edited to add requirements, please let me know if I need to add anything else, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to a TVF and eliminating the loops is the absolute right thing to do.

As I commented, consider a Calendar Table ... there are many things that can easily be accomplished.

Here is a TVF which uses an ad-hoc tally table to

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[YourFunctionName] (@D date,@I int)
Returns Table
Return (

Select WorkDate = D
      ,WorkDays = RN
 From  (
        Select D
              ,RN = -1+row_number() over( order by D)
         From  (
                Select Top ((@I+1)*2) D=dateadd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),@D)
                  From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
               ) A
         Where datename(WEEKDAY,D) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
       ) A
 Where RN=@I

)
```

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote this if I had the reputation points to do so.

Comment: @Sam You can Accept once you think is the correct answer.   Feel free to wait and see if there are other/better solutions.  :)

Comment: @Sam The subquery creates columns D and RN.  D for date and RN for row_number.   I like assigning aliases as such:  columname = some expression rather than somexpression as columnname.   For me it more readable, especially with long/complex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually got a similar requirement to this in an application at work.

Your scalar function is quite usable for around a few tens of days, however is noticeably un-performant above that.

I can't take credit for the following (as I know it was gleaned from various blogs / forums) - but stripping out some bespoke business logic and fitting to your exsting function, the following function computes the date offset and is (probably) the best performance you're going to get:

```
create or alter function dbo.DAYSADDNOWK2(@addDate date, @numDays int)
returns datetime
as
begin
  return DateAdd(day,
    case
      when ((DatePart(weekday, @addDate) + 1) % 7 + (@numDays % 5)) > 6 
    then 2 else 0 end + (@numDays % 5), 
    DateAdd(week, (@numDays / 5), @addDate)
  )
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately, I just tried it and did not get the expected result. 
For example when I enter the date '2022/11/11' and the `INT`  '2' for `numDays` this function returns '2022/11/13', but should have returned '2022/11/15'

Comment: @Sam Yeah I must have got it wrong when I was picking out some custom logic. I've re-done it above, how about now?

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you, but it still seems to be giving the incorrect output.